# Can I train model that forecasts multiple items feature?

Tags: python, machine-learning, lstm, prediction, forecast

I want a machine learning model that can forecast multiple items feature? 
For example: 
Let's tell that my model forecasts foreign exchange rate. 
If I give an input "USD", it gives me forecasted "USD" rates for the next 3 days. 
If I give an input "EUR", it gives me forecasted "EUR" rates for the next 3 days.

(Train data contained rate history of all possible currencies. Looks like below)

```
Currency |    Date    | Rate 
------------------------------
USD      | 2019-05-28 | 10.1
EUR      | 2019-05-28 | 12.3
USD      | 2019-05-29 | 10.2
EUR      | 2019-05-29 | 12.4
JPY      | 2019-05-29 | 100.4   etc.,
```

Is it possible?

If possible, what algorithm or technique should I use? Can I train all in one time?

If not possible, what is the best way to solve problems like this?

Comment: There're models can solve forecasting problems. But I don't think it's gonna work for your particular issue. As currency exchange rate impacted by too too many facts. These facts are kind of features for each prediction. Even currencies impact each other. Different currencies has each weight in the global market. And so so on.  If you just build a model for fun or just for learning resources. You can just use time series models(RNNs) give some earlier dates' rate as features then make next date rate as a label. Don't expect to have some good results or even commercialize it to earn money.

Comment: Currency is just an example. Actual problem is to forecast multiple items using only one model.

Comment: So you meant multiple items was forecasting 3 days rate in your currency example? I think even though you want to forecast 3 items. Essentially, it should be forecast one by one. As each one will be based on the previous items. The problem is actually not how to do multiple, but create a RNN type of time series model, predict one item at a time based on previous items. Do it multiple times.